# Repeet add-on upgrade from EE1 to EE2

Tags: add-on, solspace-calendar, ee1, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I am looking after an EE1 site that uses the [Repeet](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/repeet) add-on by Studio625: Brent C. Wilson. It seems to only be compatible with EE1. I am in the process of upgrading the site to EE2 and copied the version of the EE1 plugin that I have to the third_party folder anyway. I am now getting this error, which I assume is because the original add-on is not compatible with EE2.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_param() on a non-object in \system\expressionengine\third_party\repeet\pi.repeet.php on line 91
```

What should I do to fix this? Could I install the Solspace [Calendar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/calendar) add-on and would that work seamslessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look on Repeet. It just repeats the event on the template. If this is enough for you, instead of use aaaaaaaaallllll the power of Solspace Calendar, you can try to convert the add-on by yourself. There are [guidelines](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/conversion/index.html) on EllisLab website.

Solspace Calendar is a monster of complexity. If you can stay away from it, you should.

Comment: +1 for Calendar being a beast.

Comment: @foamcow no arguments there but the docs and sample code are pretty good.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. I reached out to the Brent C. Wilson the author of the plugin and he also suggested I try and update the add-on, which is way above my abilities. Looks like I am between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: So, my suggestion is to hire somebody to update it for you. I tried to take a look at the code, but I couldn't even find it to download. Its last release was at January 22, 2010, version Repeet 2.0.1. The ironic part: I discovered that Solspace Calendar was coded by Brent Wilson too.

Answer (score 2):

If you need repeating events your best bet is indeed Solspace Calendar, Repeet is EE1 only and was never ported to EE2. A seamless update however it is not, you may have to rebuild your calender completely. (it's what I would do anyway, the solspace module does a lot more than just repeating events).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what Repeet does but it's unlikely that it would be worth trying to "fix" it to work with EE2 as it's most likely going to mean completely rewriting it.

If you are looking for a way to specify repeating events then you may want to look at [Low Events](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events).

Comment: Actually, Low Events doesn't support repeating/recurring events. Look at Solspace Calendar if you need that functionality.

Comment: Dang! And there's me singing your praises ;-) You're right of course (and you should know). I was confusing 2 sites I've worked on. The one with repeating events did use Calendar. Low Events is MUCH nicer though!